# Python - Printing out all data reveived from a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I found come old TCP reverse shell made in python online and im editing it to fix it up, when it prints the output of the command it doesnt print it all if the command is too big.
This is the code for sending the commands and then printing the output

```
def send_commands(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end="")
```

I then tried this

```
def send_commands(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end="")
            while client_response != '':
                client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
                print(client_response, end="")
```

But after it run the command it prints it all out but I cant then input another command.
any idea why?

Comment: why using a loop? Why not using the first version without the size? `client_response = str(conn.recv(), "utf-8")`

Comment: Afterthought: I think this will block as well. This is TCP, so connected mode. As long as the server does not close the socket, `conn.recv()` will be blocking. You should send the data size first, then read the proper number of bytes.

Comment: Its take one argument which is the size, if you dont have a size it wont run and icreasing the size doesnt help.

Comment: My bad that did work, I guess when I tried it before I didnt increase it by enough.